# What were Russian empresses' position and policy regarding women's role in society and their rights?

Tags: russia, 18th-century, women

There are 4 empress regnants (Catherine I, Anna, Elizabeth, Catherine II) in Russian history, all of whom ruled during roughly the same historic period (18th century). 3 of them (Anna, Elizabeth, Catherine II) enjoyed absolute power and used it to actively rule.

What were their position and policy regarding women's role in society and their rights? How did they consider their rulership in the context of patriarchal views in society of that time?

**Update: some possible relevant historical context**

Catherine I: she didn't really care much about state affairs and de-facto delegated ruling to Supreme Privy Council. I haven't found any facts regarding her views on the matter, but presumably she just didn't care much.

Anna: she reestablished absolutism and actively ruled for 10 years. I haven't found any information regarding her views and policies regarding the matter.

Elizabeth: actively ruled for 21 years. [According](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_of_Russia#cite_note-FOOTNOTETalbot_Rice1970148-29) to historian Tamara Talbot Rice, "Later in life her outbursts of anger were directed either against people who were thought to have endangered Russia's security or *against women whose beauty rivaled her own*".

Catherine II: probably the most interesting case here. Having a 34-year-long extremely successful period of reign, she surely had enough power to change almost anything. She established the first state-financed higher education institution for women in Europe, but I am not sure how feminist does this count, given that the students there weren't taught any professions there, instead it was just a place to teach noble females some "good" values".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What were the reasons for female monarchs not to improve women rights?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64086/what-were-the-reasons-for-female-monarchs-not-to-improve-women-rights)

Comment: That other question was closed.   Anyway, while the women in question may have, in theory, had absolute power, in practice, they were in a precarious position and had to play a political game to ensure support for their rule.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - Since it was closed with no answers, I'm guessing it doesn't.

Comment: This seems like a far better crack at a question on this topic. I did a bit of preliminary research, and there does appear to be [some interesting things to say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_Russia#Eighteenth_century) on this topic. **It could still use an edit covering what you already know and already have researched on this**, so our users don't waste a lot of research effort on stuff you don't need.

Comment: @MoisheKohan They were both asked by the same person, this is presumably simply an attempt to ask a more focused version of the question, which has a better chance of getting an answer and not getting closed.

Comment: Why do you consider that serf women in Russian Empire were in a worse position than serf males ? At least they would not be forcibly conscripted into the army (sometimes for lifetime !) and usually would not be physically punished .Also, executions of  women were rare event, unlike executions of male convicts.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Catherine the Great had a long and extremely successful period of reigning for 34 years, I'm pretty sure she could have done almost anything at least in the end of her reign, when she had earned a lot of respect

Comment: @T.E.D. Thanks for your suggestion, I've edited the question. I did try my best to include some research, still not sure if it helps though.

Comment: Seems like [protofeminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protofeminism) and [Premodern Rulers and Postmodern Viewers](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-68771-1) might be helpful; neither seems to directly address Russia, but I have a feeling that the scholarship is in your field. Good luck

Comment: **Hint :** How did any of these queens come to power in the first place ?

Comment: Arguably Peter the Great did more for women in Russia than any of the female Empresses in that it was his actions that allowed women to rule in the first place.  In any case, a core part of the answer is that all rulers, even "absolute" rulers, have to worry about others in their country fastening onto some other person with a claim to the thrown.  But the other part of the answer is that women aren't magically feminist because they are women.   People, men and women, tend to be embedded in their culture's values.